# add new network to android device programsticly

Tags: java, android, networking, connection, wifi

I need to connect to new wifi network programaticly to my device with this code:
`

```
 try 
{
    String ssid = "\"" + SSID + "\"";
    String pass = "\"" + Pass + "\"";

    for (ScanResult result : results) 
    {
        if (result.SSID.equals(SSID)) 
        {  
            String security = getScanResultSecurity(result);
            if (security.equals("PSK")) {

                   WifiConfiguration con = new WifiConfiguration();
                   con.SSID = ssid;
                   AlertDialog a = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                   a.setMessage("in");
                   a.show();
                   con.preSharedKey = pass;
                   con.hiddenSSID = true;
                    con.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
                    con.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.Grou  pCipher.TKIP);
                    con.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.Grou  pCipher.CCMP);
                    con.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.Key  Mgmt.WPA_PSK);
                    con.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.P  airwiseCipher.TKIP);
                    con.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.P  airwiseCipher.CCMP);
                    con.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.Key  Mgmt.NONE);
                    con.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protoco  l.RSN);
                    con.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protoco  l.WPA);

                    int ntid = wifimanager.addNetwork(con);

                    wifimanager.disconnect();
                    wifimanager.enableNetwork(ntid,true);
                    wifimanager.reconnect();
                    boolean b = wifimanager.saveConfiguration();
                    if (ntid != -1 && b) {

                        AlertDialog a2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                        a2.setMessage("saved");
                        a2.show();
                    }
                }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        AlertDialog a = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        a.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        a.show();
    }
```

`
but i can't add network to my device
problem is with network configuration that can't add to networks
I cant understand why doesn't work haven't erorr but no result
help me please

Comment: What does your log say?

Comment: i can't understand a lot message and finaly failed

Comment: this is the log   mStopped=false     mHashWindowFocus=true sendUserActionEvent() mView=null   and input event receiver has already been disposed

Answer (score 0):

You should add permissions into manifest (and runtime permissions)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: i know about permission that isn't problem